# Calculated date as column name SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are numerous questions here about naming a column a variable, I don't believe this to be a duplicate of these, as I would like to use a calculation.

I would like to name my column after the previous month.   I would expect this to work:

```
SELECT isnull(sum(CASE when datepart(mm,rc.datetime) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) -1 then 1 else null end),0) AS datename(MM, dateadd(MM, -1, getdate()))
```

or for readability:

```
... AS datename(MM, dateadd(MM, -1, getdate()))
```

But it does not, I get an incorrect syntax error.  Is this achievable?  Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: only with Dynamic SQL

Comment: Changing the column name dynamically is going to cause a number of challenges down the road. Perhaps with a better understanding of what you are really trying to do here we could help find a better solution. Otherwise the dynamic sql options already posted should work fine.

Comment: One additional comment is that I prefer to avoid the abbreviations for date parts but if you are going to use them you should be consistent. In some places you use MM and others Month. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: @SeanLange Fair point for the datepart.  Regarding the problems down the line- this will populate a report, and contain counts instances of an event for the last four months,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with dynamic sql,

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''

SET @sql = 'SELECT isnull(sum(CASE 
                WHEN datepart(mm, rc.DATETIME) = ' + convert(VARCHAR(10), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())) + ' - 1
                    THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
                END), 0) AS ' + datename(MM, dateadd(MM, - 1, getdate()))

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 2):

As per comment, only achievable using dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT isnull(sum(CASE when datepart(mm,rc.datetime) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) -1 then 1 else null end),0) AS [' + datename(MM, dateadd(MM, -1, getdate())) +'];'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```